# calling sql function in ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, user-defined-functions, reportbuilder

First, I am a novice at what I am doing. I am experienced in Basic SQL but had no formal training so please be patient if I am completely wrong.

I am connecting to an SQL User_Defined Function in Report Builder but getting an incorrect syntax errpr " *Incorrect syntax near ','.* ". This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT        TicketNo, RowNo, WeighingTicket, Material, CustomerSite, 
TicketDate, quantity, NetWeight, TransportCharge, DisposalCharge, 
OtherCharge, >TotalCharge, CustomerName, ARAccountCode, ContainerType, 
                         worktypeid, NewAction
FROM            dbo.fn_WTG_AB_StandardSalesReport(,,) AS 
                fn_WTG_AB_StandardSalesReport_1
```

This was created by choosing the function as a table in query designer - don't know why it has renamed it.

This is my code for the function as this may also be the issue.

```
    [dbo].[fn_WTG_AB_StandardSalesReport]
    (   
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@StartDate date,
@EndDate date,
@Account nvarchar(60)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
-- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
SELECT TicketNo, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY worktypeid) AS RowNo, 
WeighingTicket, Material, CustomerSite, TicketDate, quantity, NetWeight, 
TransportCharge, DisposalCharge, OtherCharge, TotalCharge, 
CustomerName, ARAccountCode, ContainerType, worktypeid, CASE WHEN worktypeid 
= 3 THEN 'Gate' ELSE Action END AS NewAction
FROM            (SELECT        dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.TicketNo, 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.weighingticket, 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.Material, 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.CustomerSite,                                              
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.TicketDate, 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.quantity, 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.NetWeight, 
CASE WHEN dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.TransportCharge IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
TransportCharge END AS TransportCharge, CASE WHEN 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.DisposalCharge IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
Disposalcharge END AS DisposalCharge, CASE WHEN 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.OtherCharge IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE OtherCharge END 
AS OtherCharge,                                                     
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.TransportCharge + 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.DisposalCharge + 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.OtherCharge AS TotalCharge,                                                     
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.CustomerName, 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.ARAccountCode, dbo.ContainerType.Description AS 
ContainerType, dbo.Action.Description AS Action,                                                     
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.worktypeid
FROM            dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Action ON 
dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.ActionId = dbo.Action.ActionId LEFT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.ContainerType ON dbo.V_AB_StandardReportUnion.ContainerTypeId = 
dbo.ContainerType.ContainerTypeId                                                   
where TicketDate >= @StartDate and TicketDate<= @EndDate and ARaccountcode = 
@Account)AS Sub
```

)

Thank you very much for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax is not going to be recognized:

```
FROM dbo.fn_WTG_AB_StandardSalesReport(,,)
```

If you have default values for the arguments, then just use:

```
FROM dbo.fn_WTG_AB_StandardSalesReport()
```

Otherwise pass something in:

```
FROM dbo.fn_WTG_AB_StandardSalesReport(NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Comment: fantastic thank you! noted for future -  As it turns out now I need to set dates within the report with the way the receiving programme works - and of course I have new issues now! onto a new thread...